# react-native onResponderTerminationRequest={()=> false}, onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={()=> false} not working

Tags: scrollview, react-native, gesture

i tried using onResponderTerminationRequest={()=> false}, onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={()=> false} in the scrollview, so that it always has the control. but what is happening is that it releases the control and passes it to other scroll.

Comment: Please provide code snippet